# Zoom and Panning effect without support of Control tools

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I need to include pan effect and zoom effect without the help of control tools. The implementation in mobile and tablet so i dont need that tool bars instead of that touch zoom and drag panning effects are needed. Is it possible to implement ? Looking for suggestions

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);
      var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    maxZoom : 24,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       draggable: false
      }
```

Comment: What _control tools_ you mean?

Comment: Panning control tool(Circular disc ui) and Zoom control tool(+/- Control ui) I want to hide that. But i need the effects of panning and zooming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

Just add `disableDefaultUI: true`

```
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 10,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),

 disableDefaultUI: true, // <- this

 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
 mapOptions);
}
```

[**Example**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI)